# C# run Python process.BeginOutputReadLine() hangs till exit

Tags: c#, python, process

I am trying to exec Python from c# using process.BeginOutputReadLine()

My problem is that the receive result from python only show when the python prog is finished and not really seems to perform readline 
here is my code

```
public void ExecuteProcess()
    {


        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} ", @"C:\FB\mytestpython.py");

            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Data != null)
                {
                    //write data 

                    UpdatePythonLog(args.Data);

                }
            };

            process.Start();

            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        }

        return ;
    }
```

and here is my Python code:

```
import time

if __name__=='__main__':

    print "test1"  
    time.sleep(5) 
    print "test2"  
    time.sleep(5) 
    print "test3"  
    time.sleep(5) 
    print 'finish'
```